# Tampermonkey, call user script function from appended DOM object on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I tried almost every solution I had found here on StackOverflow but none of them helped me out. Here's my code:

```html
//Toolbar body

var toolbarbody = '<div id="scrappytoolbar" style="width:100%; height:30px; background-color: #ffea56;">' +
'<ul>' +
'<li id="litabelka">Tabelka</li>' +
'<li id="licena">Cena</li>' +
'<li>Opis</li>' +
'</div>';


//Toolbar Loading

function loadToolbar() {
 $("#article-desc-wrapper").css("margin-top", "320px");
 $("#productDetailsMainInfo").after(toolbarbody); 
 $("#productDetailsHeadlineArea").after('<button id="guziktestowy">Hehes</button>');
    
    
    
}

setTimeout(loadToolbar, 2000);
```

After appending the HTML I want to add a listener on `li#litabelka` to execute some userscript code. I tried both jQuery `onclick` and vanilla javascript `addEventListener` but the click event is not executing - nothing happens on click.

Comment: `$('#litabelka').click(function(event) { /* do something */ });`

Comment: It would be better if you also pasted the code you used for adding the click handler. Maybe I could tell you what did you do wrong...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use DOM to parse your HTML. You can do it like this:

```
var toolbarbody = '<div id="scrappytoolbar" style="width:100%; height:30px; background-color: #ffea56;">' +
'<ul>' +
'<li id="litabelka">Tabelka</li>' +
'<li id="licena">Cena</li>' +
'<li>Opis</li>' +
'</div>';
var parser = document.createElement("div");
parser.innerHTML = toolbarbody;
var toolbarElement = parser.firstChild;
// remove the toolbar from parser
parser.removeChild(toolbarElement);
```

Now actual DOM elements are in `toolbarElement` so you can apply listeners on them:

```
toolbarElement.querySelector("#litabelka").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // do something on click here
});
```

But remember that now you need to append `toolbarElement`, not the HTML string:

```
function loadToolbar() {
    $("#article-desc-wrapper").css("margin-top", "320px");
    // we now append DOM element
    $("#productDetailsMainInfo").after(toolbarElement); 
    $("#productDetailsHeadlineArea").after('<button id="guziktestowy">Hehes</button>');
}
```

Also note that it's better to wait for `load` or [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) events than using `setTimeout`.